# Incomplete types in collection iterators

Tags: c++, templates, stl, incomplete-type

I wrote myself a custom STL-style container which internally uses an AVL tree to organize data. Now, in a project, I want to have an iterator for it as a member:

```
class vertex {
    ...
    avl_tree<vertex>::iterator partner;
    ...
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
error: ‘avl_tree<T, A>::node::data’ has incomplete type
         T data;
           ^
```

From what I've read on SO and other websites, `vertex` is an incomplete type until it is completely defined. `avl_tree<T,A>::node` is a private struct I use to manage the tree and it has `T data;` amongst its members which is however illegal if `T` is incomplete. Oddly enough, when I use `std::list` instead, there is no such problem, which I understand is undefined behavior.

Is there an easy way around this problem? The `avl_tree<T,A>::iterator` internally maintains just a pointer `node *ptr` which should not be a problem for incomplete types as pointers have fixed size. But I don't want to expose the `node` class to the `public`, I want to use `iterator`s. Still, the `iterator` will always have the same size, regardless of the templete parameter, so is there a way to force the compiler to acknowledge that fact?

---

Struct overview:

```
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
class avl_tree {
private:
    class node {
    public:
        T data;
        avl_tree *tree;
        short depth;
        size_type n;
        node *parent;
        node *left_child;
        node *right_child;
    };
public:
    class iterator {
    private:
        node *ptr;
    };
private:
    using NodeAlloc = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::template rebind_alloc<node>;
    NodeAlloc alloc;
    node root;
};
```

The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jgreitemann/avl-tree/blob/master/avl_tree.hpp).

Comment: Does your `avl_tree` store a node directly (not a pointer to it) -- ex: for  the root node? A few more code snippets showing the data members of your node/tree/iterator would be appreciated (methods can be omitted --  just like a "struct overview").

Comment: The recursive object definition is always a problem that I see solved through indirection, either something like `avl_tree<vertex*>::iterator partner` or `avl_tree<boost::recursive_wrapper<vertex>>::iterator partner`.  The latter simply wraps a dynamically allocated object giving you your value semantics back, which was designed to exactly deal with situations like these.  What solution works best for you depends, but basically with a recursive data structure like this, you need indirection.

Comment: Easy way IMO at a teeny cost to efficiency for the root: add the indirection there to break the recursion. Store `node* root`. It should only make a negligible difference in exchange for greater generality for the whole container. If you measure it and find it to be pesky enough as a hotspot, you can implement a fixed alloc for the whole tree and potentially improve everything (linked structures can benefit enormously from a less general-purpose alloc)
.

Comment: @Ike I did end up changing root to `node*`. I could not measure any difference in performance. Since the tree is stored on the heap anyway, the additional indirection at the root did not hurt, it suppose.

Comment: @Jonas Yeah, it's a pretty negligible overhead especially if your tree is not super shallow. It does hurt a little teeny bit in terms of spatial locality, but typically quite trivial and negligible for any healthy-sized tree. You can gain back spatial locality for the root and even various nodes with an allocator of some sort (ex: one which starts with a 4k block stored inside avl_tree directly, unrolled list-style rep), but might be overkill here.

Comment: @Jonas Severing the link at the root is a good starting strategy though -- with an eye towards allocators if you want more speed. That's also why `std::list` can avoid the recursive type dependency in this kind of context: it stores a pointer to the tail and head, and thus doesn't need a complete type definition for a node (and likewise thus doesn't need a complete type definition for `T`) upon instantiation. Same kind of thing with `std::map`, it typically stores a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Complete Types

First, let's look at a simple example of what is required in order to define a UDT (user-defined type).

```
struct Foo
{
     struct Bar bar;
};
```

Given the above code, the compiler can only properly build it if the definition of `struct Bar` is understood. Otherwise it cannot know how to align this `bar` data member along with how large the structure actually is (and how much padding to add to ensure its proper alignment).

As a result, to be able to define `Foo` in this way requires `Bar` to likewise be defined. The type dependencies look like this:

```
Foo->Bar
```

If we change the code above to this:

```
struct Foo
{
     struct Bar* bar;
};
```

... suddenly we're looking at a very different scenario. In this case, `Bar` is allowed to be an incomplete type (declared but not defined) as `Foo` only stores a pointer to it. A pointer is effectively a POD (plain old data type). Its size and alignment requirements do not vary whether it's pointing to a `Bar` or a `Baz`. As a result, the type dependency here is basically:

```
Foo->POD
```

Therefore we can compile this code even though the definition of `Bar` is unknown. Of course if the compiler encounters code which is trying to access the members of `Bar` or constructing it or doing anything which requires information about `Bar`, specifically, it would generate an error unless the definition of `Bar` is available at that time.

### Circular/Recursive Type Dependencies

Let's look at a simple example of a recursive type dependency:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Foo next;
};
```

For this case, in order to properly define `Foo`, we must properly define `Foo`. Whoops -- infinite recursion. Even if this was somehow allowed, the system would want to allocate an infinite amount of memory for `Foo`. In this case, the type dependencies look like this:

```
Foo->Foo->Foo->...
```

The same problem persists even if we introduce a new type in the middle:

```
struct Foo
{
     struct Node next;
};

struct Node
{
     struct Foo element;
};
```

Here we still get a compiler error due to the cyclical nature of the type dependencies which look like this:

```
Foo->Node->Foo->Node->Foo->...
```

Besides that, we have a chicken or the egg kind of problem. `Node` cannot possibly be defined at the time `Foo` is defined if `Foo` precedes `Node`, and `Node` cannot possibly be defined at the time `Foo` is defined if `Node` precedes `Foo`.

To break the cycle, we can add an indirection:

```
struct Foo
{
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node
{
    struct Foo element;
};
```

Now we have:

```
Foo->POD
Node->Foo->POD
```

... which is valid, avoids circular type dependencies, and compiles just fine.

### Tree Example

Getting closer to your tree example, let's look at a case like this:

```
template <class T>
struct Tree
{
     struct Node
     {
         T element;
     };
     Node root;
};
```

In this case, the type dependencies look like this:

```
Tree->Node->T->...
```

This will compile fine provided that `T` does not depend on the definition of `Tree` or `Node`.

Nevertheless, in your case, `T` is a `vertex` which depends on the type definition of a tree which stores a node which stores a vertex. As a result, we have this kind of scenario:

```
avl_tree<vertex>->node->vertex->avl_tree<vertex>->node->vertex->...
```

... and thus we have that circular type dependency again. One of the easiest ways to sever this dependency, and perhaps the most commonly-employed for a linked structure like this, is to store the `root/head/tail` as a pointer.

```
template <class T>
struct Tree
{
     struct Node
     {
         T element;
     };
     Node* root;
};
```

With this, we've severed the type dependencies like so:

```
Tree->POD
Node->T->...
```

... or, adapted to your example:

```
avl_tree<vertex>->POD
node->vertex->avl_tree<vertex>->POD
```

... which is completely fine and breaks the cycle.

You might be wondering why, conceptually, this needs the full `avl_tree` type definition:

```
avl_tree<vertex>::iterator partner;
```

The iterator here is fine since it stores a pointer to a node which is a POD. Yet the problem here is that we're trying to access a member of `avl_tree`, even though it's just a typename, and this requires the compiler to have a complete type definition of `avl_tree` (it doesn't work quite at the ideal kind of granular level we might like). This recurses to require the complete definition of `node` which then requires the complete definition of `vertex`.

> Oddly enough, when I use `std::list` instead, there is no such problem

This is because `std::list` typically looks like this (give or take some minor variations):

```
template <class T, ...>
class list
{
public:
    ...

private:
    struct node
    {
         node* next;
         node* prev;
         T element;
    };
    ...
    node* head;
    node* tail;
};
```

The relevant type dependencies here look like this:

```
list<T>->POD
node->T->...
```

### Breaking Type Dependencies

From the above we can see that we can sever/break a type dependency by introducing an indirection through a pointer. In doing so, we no longer require a user-defined type definition and can instead change a UDT dependency to a simple POD dependency.

The indirection can be placed anywhere you like, but for a linked structure, typically the most convenient place is at the `root/head/tail` of the structure. This prevents the clients using your linked structure from having to worry about these recursive/circular type dependencies.

### Cost of Indirection

One of the things I hear a lot is "the cost of indirection", as though this is very expensive. It all depends on memory access patterns and how they relate to the memory hierarchy going all the way from a register to paging in memory from secondary stage. While thinking about this as the "cost of indirection" is a simple and general kind of way to look at it since pointers can point all over the place in memory, what really makes the difference here is how we're accessing memory as a result of deferencing those pointers.

Even a linked list can be quite efficient if we're traversing it sequentially across a contiguous memory space where multiple nodes fit into a cache line and are accessed prior to eviction. Where they're often not so fast is due to the fact that often the nodes are allocated by a general-purpose allocator and not all at once, scattering and fragmenting their contents across the memory space and leading to cache misses during traversal. It's the memory layout that makes the biggest difference here.

So if you're ever worried about the cost of an indirection required to break a type dependency, don't. It's often the wrong thing to worry about unless it's merely about the memory size of a pointer in a very granular case. Instead look to the way the memory is allocated, seek locality of reference. With the right kind of memory allocation strategy, even linked structures which inevitably rely on a lot of indirection can become very efficient.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you very much for taking the time, much appreciated. The thing I kind of missed was to think of `avl_tree<T>::iterator` as accessing a member, just one of type `typename`. That sort of explains why the compiler needs to figure out the againment of `avl_tree<T>` at that point already. Thanks too for the details on the cost of indirection. I will try to write a custom allocator and run some tests for the fun of it.

Comment: @Jonas If you are really interested in that memory allocator side, I included one here (see bottom part -- shameless plug): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580869/skip-lists-are-they-really-performing-as-good-as-pugh-paper-claim/34003558#34003558. It shows a basic O(1) fixed allocator. I used it to speed up the allocation of a skip list's nodes but the code there should work for anything (`class FixedAlloc`).

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is nothing wrong with `node` or `iterator` type. The problem is that you use recursive type definition

```
class vertex {
    ...
    avl_tree<vertex>::iterator partner;
    ...
}
```

You're trying to use type that is still not fully defined (`vertex`). So on instantiation of `node root` you've got an error, compiler does not know the size of `T`.

Here is the small example that simulates your problem

```
template<typename T>
struct A {

    struct B {

        T data;

    };

    struct C {

        B* b;

    };

    B root;
};

struct D {

    A<D>::C ad;

};

int main() {
    D d;
}
```

`A` is your `avl_tree`, `B` is the `node` and `C` is the `iterator`. And the error is the same

> error: ‘A::B::data’ has incomplete type

Now there are multiple ways to fix it. First one is to change type of `ad` in the `D` type to

```
A<D*>::C ad;
```

However as you have mentioned, there is no such problem for the `list` from STL (or the `vector`). And here is the deal, the type of `root` in the `A` should be `B*` or `B&`, not `B`. But if you will use `B*` you will need to take care of the memory allocation.

Comment: This indeed did the trick. However, I still don't understand 100 per cent why there was a problem with the root. You said: "So on instantiation of `node root` you've got an error, compiler does not know the size of `T`." But at that point (where vertex is defined) I only use `avl_tree<T,A>::iterator` and it does not instantiate a `node` directly or thru `avl_tree` but only keeps a pointer `node*` which should be fine.

Comment: @Jonas The reason is that the definition of `iterator` uses definition of `avl_tree`. The instance of `avl_tree` is not needed, however the compiler should know the size of `avl_tree` type and to calculate it the size of `vertex` is needed.