# Does the C++ standard specify the type dependencies of standard containers?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

In "*[Codependent types with unordered_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691408/codependent-types-with-unordered-map)*" it was observed that
`std::unordered_map<Key, Value>` has a type dependency on `Value` in libstdc++ (which is unexpected) and has no type dependency on `Value` in libc++ and MSVC.

In general, does the ISO C++ specification talk about the type dependencies of containers at all? If so could you point me to relevant parts?

**Type dependency:** I'm not sure if there is a formal definition of type dependency in the ISO C++ spec, but for the purposes of this post, let us say a `type A` has type dependency on `type B` if A cannot be compiled with the forward declaration of B alone. Example:

```cpp
struct Val; // forward declaration of Val
struct Container {
  Val v;
}; // Compile error; Type Val is incomplete. Container has a type dependency on Val
```

```
struct Val; // forward declaration of Val
struct Container2 {
  Val *v;
}; // Compiles. Container2 does not have type dependency on Val
```

Comment: *Type dependency* is a term with special meaning in C++.  Consider rewording.

Comment: @L.F. Thank you for pointing this out. A web search did not lead me to the relevant parts of the standard. Would be grateful if you can point me to it (definition of type dependency that is)

Comment: The term is defined in [\[temp.dep\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep#def:expression,type-dependent).

Comment: @L.F. That sounds good, I just cannot think of a better alternative. If you have a suggestion I would be very happy to hear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be looking for this:

> **[res.on.functions]/2** In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> (2.5) — if an incomplete type (6.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

---

Of various standard containers, **[containers]** section specifies that `std::forward_list`, `std::list` and `std::vector` can be instantiated with incomplete types. E.g.

> **[vector.overview]/3** An incomplete type `T` may be used when instantiating `vector` if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements (20.5.3.5.1). `T` shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of `vector` is referenced.

There's similar wording for `forward_list` and `list`.

Comment: This looks very promising. I am diving deep into this and will get back. Thank you

Comment: From boost docs: "Finally C++17 added support for incomplete types in std::vector, std::list and std::forward_list (see N4569: Minimal incomplete type support for standard containers, revision 4 for details), but no other containers like std::set/map/unordered_set/unordered_map, "

Comment: Really appreciate this insightful answer